# How to set the size of MsgBox/MessageBox in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I want to have something like a button named "Check Out" that will serve as preview for customer's info and his/her order. I want to resize the message box because whenever I am displaying a message. It turns out to be like "Name:Alexander........". the message box cannot display the whole string because its size is small.

Comment: It should resize according to the strings length... On another note you ***can't directly***. Although you can create your own class to do so...

Comment: could you please include the screenshot of current display

Comment: Don't use a message box for this. Create a new form that will Autoresize to it's contents. You can still return values from the form by creating properties and accessing them before the form is disposed.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. maybe I should start researching about that creating new form for my display.

Comment: MsgBox and MessageBox automatically resize to fit the contents, without code we can't help you any more than that